# Log halt messages in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've set up a sinatra web service which accepts JSON-formatted POST messages. It performs various validations on the incoming data and if there are any problems it calls `halt 400, "You're doing it wrong"` or something to that effect, with a bit more detail on exactly what they're doing wrong.

The error messages (e.g. "You're doing it wrong") are sent to the client just fine, but I'd also like to have them logged on the server so I can see where people are having problems with their client implementations. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [logging](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Logging) and `Exception#backtrace`. You may need to do something like `raise RuntimeError` (or some other error) then catch the error and send the results of `error.backtrace` to your log.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Carl Zulauf for pointing me in the right direction. In the end I replaced all my `halt 400, "message"` calls with calls to this method:

```
def invalid_request! message
  logger.info "Request rejected: #{message}\n#{caller(1).join "\n"}"
  halt 400, message
end
```

Comment: You can use `caller` method instead of raising & rescuing exceptions to get a backtrace.